# How to set db adapter to Validator NoRecordExists and use it in controller?

Tags: zend-framework2

I recently started learning ZF2 and hope someone can help me with this.

I am working my way through Rob Allen's Zend Framework 2 Tutorial (many thanks to @rob-allen).

Also I use a solution of @AlloVince and @Maciej [How to set db adapter to Validator RecordExists in Zend Framework 2](/questions/13818525) (many thanks to both authors for it) and I confused because didn't to use this solution in **editAction**.

I see `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object` in `'adapter' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')`.

1) In the Module.php added

> ```
> public function getServiceConfig()
> {
>     return array(
>         'invokables' => array(
>             'RegionModel' => 'FcLibraries\Model\Region', //<-- added it
>         ),
>         'factories' => array(
>             'FcLibraries\Model\RegionTable' => function ($sm) {
>                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
>                 $table = new RegionTable($dbAdapter);
>                 return $table;
>             },
>         ),
>     );
> }
> ```

2) In the Region.php added

> ```
> /**
>  * @var
>  */
> protected $serviceLocator;
> /**
>  * @param \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
>  * @return Library
>  */
> public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
> {
>     $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
>     return $this;
> }
> /**
>  * @return \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface
>  */
> public function getServiceLocator()
> {
>     return $this->serviceLocator;
> }
> ```

and

> ```
>         $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
>             'name' => 'name',
>             'required' => true,
>             'filters' => $this->_filters,
>             'validators' => array(
>                 array(
>                     'name' => 'StringLength',
>                     'options' => array(
>                         'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
>                         'min' => 1,
>                         'max' => 30,
>                     ),
>                 ),
>                 array(
>                     'name'    => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
>                     'options' => array(
>                         'table' => $this->table,
>                         'field' => 'name',
>                         //'exclude' => array(
>                         //    'field' => 'id',
>                         //    'value' => $this->id
>                         //),
>                         'adapter' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'),
>                     ),
>                 ),
>             ),
>         )));
> ```

3) In the RegionController.php in addAction using

> $model = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RegionModel');

instead of `$model = new Region();`.

This works fine for addAction, But I can not understand how I should use it in editAction.

My

> ```
> public function editAction()
> {
>     $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
>     if (!$id) {
>         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/region', array(
>             'action' => 'add'
>         ));
>     }
>     $data = $this->getRegionTable()->get($id);
>     $form = new RegionForm();
>     $form->bind($data);
>     $form->get('submitBtn')->setAttribute('value', 'Save');
>     $request = $this->getRequest();
>     if ($request->isPost()) {
>         $form->setInputFilter($data->getInputFilter());
>         $form->setData($request->getPost());
>         if ($form->isValid()) {
>             $this->getRegionTable()->save($form->getData());
>             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/regions');
>         }
>     }
>     return array(
>         'id' => $id,
>         'form' => $form,
>     );
> }
> ```

My RegionTable has the following code:

> ```
> /**
>  * @param \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $adapter
>  */
> public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
> {
>     $this->adapter = $adapter;
>     $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
>     $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Region());
>     $this->initialize();
> }
> public function get($id)
> {
>     $id = (int)$id;
>     $rowSet = $this->select(array('id' => $id));
>     $row = $rowSet->current();
>     if (!$row) {
>         throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
>     }
>     return $row;
> }
> ```

Many thanks to all who will answer my question.

Best regards, Ruslan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the form filter from the entity which you gathered from the table you should instantiate a new entity via the service manager to use the database adapter.

You have a few options:

1. Move the input filter to its own class and instantiate via the service manager so your database adapter is injected.
2. Change the prototype object in the table gateway factory to be instantiated via the service manager factory.
3. Instantiate a separate entity via the service manager and get the input filter from there.

I personally would go for option 1 as it separates the code better.

Some examples:

**Option 1 (my choice):**

This involves moving the filter to its own file and class, creating a factory for it whilst injecting the database adapter. We will then, in the controller, get the filter via the service manager and apply the filter to the form.

So first move your filter to a file in ModName\src\ModName\Form\RegionFilter.php, obviosly replacing ModName with your module name.

and change the code to like so:

```php
<?php
namespace Region\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class RegionFilter implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

    /**
     * @var inputFilter
     */
    protected $inputFilter;

    /**
     * @var Database Adapter
     */
    protected $dbAdapter;

    /**
     * @param \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface $inputFilter
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    /**
     * @param \Zend\Db\Adapter $dbAdapter
     */
    public function __construct(Adapter $dbAdapter) {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return Zend\Db\Adapter
     */
    public function getDbAdapter() {
        return $this->dbAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter
     * 
     * Get the input filter (build it first)
     */
    public function getInputFilter() {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {

            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => $this->_filters,
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 1,
                            'max' => 30,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
                        'options' => array(
                            'table' => $this->table,
                            'field' => 'name',
                            //'exclude' => array(
                            //    'field' => 'id',
                            //    'value' => $this->id
                            //),
                            'adapter' => $this->getDbAdapter(),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));
                    $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
?>
```

You would then create a factory like so in Module.php:

```php
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'ModName\Form\RegionFilter' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                return new RegionFilter($dbAdapter);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

And finally in your controller, just do the following:

```php
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $filter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModName\Form\RegionFilter');
    $form->setInputFilter($filter->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($request->getPost());
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->getRegionTable()->save($form->getData());
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/regions');
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

This involves constructing your table with an instance of `Region` injected. Then you can set the prototype to this.

So in your table construct:

```php
public function __construct(Adapter $adapter, Region $region)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype($region);
    $this->initialize();
}
```

And then your factory:

```php
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'RegionModel' => 'FcLibraries\Model\Region', 
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'FcLibraries\Model\RegionTable' => function ($sm) {
                $region = $sm->get('RegionModel');
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table = new RegionTable($dbAdapter,$region);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

You should be able to leave the rest of the code as is. Eg the controller. Now I have not tested this method so I'm not 100% it will work, but I think it should. The other two methods I have used previously myself.

**Option 3 (the simplest):**

This involves getting a separate region model via the service manager and using that to apply the input filter to the form.

```php
public function editAction()
{
    $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/region', array(
            'action' => 'add'
        ));
    }
    $data = $this->getRegionTable()->get($id);
    $form = new RegionForm();
    $form->bind($data);
    $form->get('submitBtn')->setAttribute('value', 'Save');
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $region = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RegionModel');
        $form->setInputFilter($region->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->getRegionTable()->save($form->getData());
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/regions');
        }
    }
    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'form' => $form,
    );
}
```

I have not tested the code but you should get the gist. Any questions just ask.

Comment: @Aydi-Hassan thanks a lot. I tried the option 2. It works.

Now make refactoring a module as you described in option 1 and have an error. 
Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb::setAdapter() must be an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, null given, called in \vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator.php on line 142 and defined in \Zend\Validator\Db\AbstractDb.php on line 168
Currently looking for a reason.

Comment: Sorry there were some issues with the code, I've updated the SbAdapter Namespace and added a var for it

Comment: This is beautiful. @Aydin, I am very grateful to you, you've been very helpful. Option 1 works now. I hope this will also help other people.

Comment: You had me at Option 1. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For doing the validation for "Username already exists or not", Do the following simple way of Service Manager config settings like:

// config/autoload/global.php

```
return array(
   'db' => array(
   'driver'   => 'Pdo',
   'dsn'      => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
),

 'service_manager' => array(
   'factories' => array(
     'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($serviceManager) {
        $adapterFactory = new Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory();
           $adapter = $adapterFactory->createService($serviceManager);

           \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($adapter);

           return $adapter;
     }
  ),
)
```

);

and add the following array into getInputFilter():

```
array(
  'table'   => 'users',
  'field'   => 'username',
  'adapter' => \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter();
)
```